# Download 4 apps at a time during restore from iCloud backup?

Tags: icloud, restore, ios, iphone

I noticed that usually when you download multiple apps on iOS 6, it will download 4 at a time. I had to restore my phone from an iCloud backup twice in the past week. The first time it was only downloading one app at a time. The second time it began downloading 4 apps at a time but then switched to downloading one at a time again. I'm not sure if I did anything to change its behavior.

Is there any way to have it download multiple apps again during this restore process?

If I try clicking on an app which says "Waiting...", it will say loading on both apps, but only the one I clicked on last will actually be downloading. The other apps progress does not change until the 2nd one is finished.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior that you can't change. I don't know why, I guess it's just the way Apple wanted it to work.